# Pandas dividing every N column by a fixed column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given a dataframe like this

```
   ImageId | Width | Height | lb0 | x0 | y0 | lb1 | x1 | y1 | lb2 | x2 | y2
0  abc     | 200   | 500    | ijk | 4  | 8  | zyx | 15 | 16 | www | 23 | 42
1  def     | 300   | 800    | ijk | 42 | 23 | zyx | 16 | 15 | www | 8  | 4
2  ghi     | 700   | 400    | ijk | 9  | 16 | zyx | 17 | 24 | www | 43 | 109
3  jkl     | 500   | 100    | ijk | 42 | 23 |     |    |    |     |    |
...
```

#### Question:

- How can I divide columns `[x0, x1]` by `[Width]` and `[y0, y1]` by `[Height]`?

---

I can set a constant value to all the `x*` columns with

```
df.iloc[:, 4::3] = SOME_SCALAR_VALUE
```

But what I want to do is something along the lines of

```
df.iloc[:, 4::3] = df.iloc[:, 4::3] / df['Width']
```

which returns

> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (62936,) (8,)

Comment: why don't you divide speratly.? like `df['x0'] = df['x0'] / df['Width']`

Comment: It is hard to try on your sample but it is probably an axis issue. Try `df.iloc[:, 4::3] = df.iloc[:, 4::3].div(df['Width'], axis=0)`.

Comment: @SreeramTP doing that gives me the wrong values. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51423766/pandas-adding-scalar-value-to-numeric-column for details

Comment: @user2285236 That raises this error: `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (70803,) (7867,) `. Any ideas?

Comment: You may not be operating on the same DataFrame or you might have a typo in the slices because `df.iloc[:, 4::3]` and `df['Width']` have to have the same number of rows (if they are the same DataFrame) but your error suggests otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `div` with `axis=0` parameter:

```
df.iloc[:, 4::3].div(df['Width'], axis=0)
```

Output:

```
         x0        x1        x2
0  0.020000  0.075000  0.115000
1  0.140000  0.053333  0.026667
2  0.012857  0.024286  0.061429
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
df.iloc[:,4:3] = df.iloc[:,4:3].apply(lambda x: x/df['Width'],axis=0)
```

Comment: This is looking good. I'm getting `TypeError: ("unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'NoneType' and 'int'", 'occurred at index xmin1')` Any suggestions there?

Comment: `apply` + `lambda` is not recommended for vectorisable operations.

Comment: you may check your types `df.dtypes` and force to be numeric `df.iloc[:,4:3] = df.iloc[:,4:3].astype(int)` or `float` if possible