# Pandas adding scalar value to numeric column?

Tags: python, pandas

Given a dataframe like this

```
   ImageId | Width | Height | lb0 | x0 | y0 | lb1 | x1 | y1 | lb2 | x2 | y2
0  abc     | 200   | 500    | ijk | 115| 8  | zyx | 15 | 16 | www | 23 | 42
1  def     | 300   | 800    | ijk | 91 | 23 | zyx | 16 | 15 | www | 8  | 4
2  ghi     | 700   | 400    | ijk | 230| 16 | zyx | 17 | 24 | www | 43 | 109
3  jkl     | 500   | 100    | ijk | 46 | 23 |     |    |    |     |    |
...
```

When I try to add to a column with

```
df['x0'] = df['x0'] + 1
```

I now get column `x0` as follows:

```
151
127
266
82
```

#### Question:

- How do I add a scalar value to a whole column in Pandas?

Comment: Seems like you don't have an `int` dtype?  `df['x0'].astype(int) + 1`?

Comment: That was it. If I add `df['x0'].astype(int)` then it works as expected. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably don't have an `int` dtype. Doing

```
df['x0'] = df['x0'].astype(int) + 1
```

should work

Comment: please improve your answer to make it usable for a non integer value

Comment: @MarineGalantin I'm sorry? The question doesn't make any reference to a non integer value. If you need help with a different set up, feel free to open a new question

Comment: I understand, but I would feel bad opening a new question when at multiple times in the question, the author mentions scalar and not integer scalar :)

Comment: Editing the question (and then updating the answer) would do to resolve the conflict aroused due to integer and non-integer values. 
( mentioning: @rafaelc )

Comment: Editing the question (and then updating the answer) would do to resolve the conflict aroused due to integer and non-integer values. 
( and mentioning: @MarineGalantin )

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that the `dtype` of your column is `int`  and your code doesn't work, you can do something like this.

```
df['x0'] = df['x0'].apply(lambda x : x+1)
```

OR

```
df.loc[:,'x0'] += 1
```

Comment: Why downvote.?? Expalining what is wrong will be helpful

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I assume someone didn't like your use of `.apply(lambda)`...

Comment: @SreeramTP I'd say it makes no sense to use `apply` to perform trivial operations such as `+`, which are by nature vectorized